# Resource vs EmbeddedResource which one is preferred for Images?

Tags: c#, wpf, mono.addins

I have a WPF application which has tons of images. I heard that Build Action - Embedded Resource makes the picture file built into the assembly hence increasing the size it would take in memory to load it.

Is it true ? I am using [Mono.Addins](http://monoaddins.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom%20Extension%20Node%20Types&referringTitle=Reference%20Manual&ANCHOR#Getting%20add-in%20types,%20files%20and%20resources) project which only supports loading Embedded Resource unless I want to use other methods of discovery + Loading.

Is Embedded Resource bad for images ?

Answer (score 5):

> I heard that Build Action - Embedded Resource makes the picture file built into the assembly hence increasing the size it would take in memory to load it.

Actually, both `Resource` and `Embedded Resource` cause the image to be embedded in the assembly, but not in the same way. If you want to use the image in a WPF `Image` control, you need to use `Resource`. If you use `Embedded Resource`, you will have to manually extract it and create a WPF `ImageSource` from it.